# JSON.NET serializeObject vb.net error

Tags: json, vb.net, class, serialization, json.net

```
Public Class Json_Info
    Public fruit As Json_Info_Fruit
End Class

Public Class Json_Info_Fruit
    Public aa As String
    Public ab As Integer
End Class

Public Class Main
    Private Sub Example()
        Dim fruitInfo As New Json_Info
        fruitInfo.fruit.aa = "apple" 'Error On This Line
        fruitInfo.fruit.ab = 1

        Dim output As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginInfo)
        MsgBox(output)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Error On **fruitInfo.fruit.aa = "apple"**

What's wrong? (what.. all examples on json.net is C# examples. no one vb.net. so hard to learn)

i need to make..

```
{
    "fruit": {
        "aa": "apple",
        "ab": 1
    }
}
```

sry for my bad english :P help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: *"Error On fruitInfo.fruit.aa = "apple""* Always say ***what*** error, not just that you're getting one. In this case, we could guess, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialize `fruitInfo.fruit`, and there's no `Json_Info` constructor to do it, so the `fruit` property is initially `Nothing`.

Either:

1. Add a constructor to initialize it, or
2. If you want to do it per-use, be sure you do that:

   ```
   Dim fruitInfo As New Json_Info
   fruitInfo.fruit = New Json_Info_Fruit        ' This is the new line
   fruitInfo.fruit.aa = "apple"
   ```
3. Or *maybe* you can use the `New` keyword in the declaration of the `fruit` member, I don't now VB.Net well and MSDN isn't being useful:

   ```
   Public fruit As New Json_Info_Fruit
   ```

   But again, double-check that.